# JTS Vividsolutions API: compute First (direct) geodetic problem

Tags: java, geodesy, geodesic, jts-topology-suite

I'm using the popular [JTS Vividsolutions](http://www.vividsolutions.com/jts/JTSHome.htm) API for Java. I'm struggling to find if I can perform calculation of the [First (direct) geodetic problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesy#First_.28direct.29_geodetic_problem) with the API.
Is there a way to calculate this with this API? It seems that simple one method not exist, but maybe using some combinations of existing methods of that API.

Note - I'm not looking for solutions of implementing the First (direct) geodetic problem algorithm using Java+JTS suite.

Comment: Feels like a stupid workaround but at least JTS can rotate. Create a vertical line with correct length and rotate it and find where the end point of the line travels.

Comment: @user30184 actually very elegant solution

Comment: @user30184 Thanks, found the solution and put it here for others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I found by myself the solution thanks to @user30184 comment.

The key principal is using JTS rotation via [Math Transformation](http://docs.geotools.org/stable/userguide/library/api/jts.html).

```
//my base point
Coordinate ancorPoint = placeCoordinate;
//create orthogonal point in distance of 0.001 arc degrees
Coordinate endingCoordinate = new Coordinate(placeCoordinate.x+0.001, placeCoordinate.y);
//rotate by 90 degrees = pi/2 = 1.57 (radians)
AffineTransform affineTransform = AffineTransform.getRotateInstance(1.57, ancorPoint.x, ancorPoint.y);
MathTransform mathTransform = new AffineTransform2D(affineTransform);
try {
    //save the result "in place" - modify endingCoordinate to save memory
    JTS.transform(endingCoordinate, endingCoordinate, mathTransform);
} catch (Exception e) {}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would much rather suggest doing it manually since the math is simple. This will be much faster than using so many potentially complex methods.

```
public static Point createPointInDistanceAtAngle(Point anchor, 
                                      double distance, double angle) {

    double dx = distance * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(angle));
    double dy = distance * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(angle));

    double x = anchor.getX() + dx;
    double y = anchor.getY() + dy;

    GeometryFactory geometryFactory = new GeometryFactory(); // maybe pass one
    Point point = geometryFactory.createPoint(new Coordinate(x, y));

    return point;
}
```